# Interpretation of bayesian 95% prediction interval

Tags: probability, bayesian

Assume the following bivariate regression model:

$y_i = \beta x_i + u_i$ where $u_i$ is i.i.d $N(0, \sigma^2 = 9)$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$.

Assume a noninformative prior of the form:

$p(\beta) \propto constant$, then it can be shown that the posterior pdf for $\beta$ is:

$p(\beta|\mathbf{y}) = (18\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{18}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 (\beta - \hat{\beta})^2\right]$

where $\displaystyle{\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}$

Now consider the value of $y$ with a given future value of $x$, $x_{n+1}$:

$y_{n+1} = \beta x_{n+1} + u_{n+1}$ where $u_{n+1}$ is i.i.d $N(0, \sigma^2 = 9)$ , then we can [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462746/finding-the-marginal-posterior-distribution-of-future-prediction-y-n1?rq=1):

$p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}) = \int_{\beta} p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \beta, \mathbf{y}) p(\beta|\mathbf{y})d\beta$ is a normal density with:

$E[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}] = \hat{\beta}x_{n+1}$

and

$\displaystyle{var[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}] = \frac{9[x_{n+1}^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2]}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}$

Thus the posterior probability density function for $y_{n+1}$, conditional on $x_{n+1}$, is given by:
$$p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}) = \left(\frac{18\pi\left[x_{n+1}^2 + \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\right]}{ \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left\{-\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}{18\left(x_{n+1}^2 + \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}\right)}\left(y_{n+1}-\hat{\beta}x_{n+1}\right)^2\right\}$$

---

Now the question is: Specify a 95% prediction interval for $y_{n+1}$ and carefully interpret it. What aspect(s) of the data generating process does the interval fail to accommodate our uncertainty about?

---

I'm not exactly too sure on how to answer the question but here's my attempt:

So essentially we need to find some $a$ and $b$ such that $P(a < y_{n+1} < b) = \int_{a}^b p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \mathbf{y}) dy_{n+1} = 95\%$

Now we know that $y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \mathbf{y} \sim N(m, v^2)$ where $m = E[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}]$ and $v^2 = var[y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}]$, Hence:
$$\frac{y_{n+1}-m}{v} \sim N(0,1)$$
$$P(-1.96 < \frac{y_{n+1}-m}{v} < 1.96) = 95\%$$
$$P(-1.96v+m < y_{n+1} < 1.96v+m) = 95\%$$

Now because we are conditioning on $x_{n+1}$ and looking at the expression for $v$ and $m$, we see that both $v$ and $m$ are known values. So we can take $a = -1.96v+m$ and $b = 1.96v+m$.

Now I know that this $a$ and $b$ are not unique, ie, we can select many other possibilities of $a$ and $b$ which yields a probability of $95\%$... but how does this relate to answering the part of the question that asks what aspects of the data generating process this interval fails to accommodate?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hint: the specific $a$ and $b$ were derived _given_ that you are constructing a confidence interval that is _symmetric_  around the predicted value.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thank you for the hint. Yes, I am aware that both the upper and lower bounds were derived given symmetry, however I am still unable to put into words exactly what aspects of this interval fails to accomodate uncertainty regarding the DGP. Eg, there could be an infinite number of choices of $a$ and $b$, so picking one that is symmetric around $y_{n+1}$ may put less emphasis on extremely large/small values? I'm really not sure.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Am I on the right track? :)

Comment: A symmetric confidence interval is the consequence of a maintained hypothesis, which is not tested, being part of the initial specification: that $u$ is normal. I believe that the question you face does not ask you to question the assumption of normality. What appears more important here is: have we adequately accommodated the uncertainty about $\beta$?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Ah yes good point regarding the uncertainty about $\beta$, however isn't that a bit irrelevant here since we marginalised out $\beta$ and only deal with the marginal posterior of $y_{n+1}$ given $x_{n+1}$ and $\mathbf{y}$? In other words, $\displaystyle{p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1},\mathbf{y}) = E_{\beta|\mathbf{y}}[p(y_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \beta, \mathbf{y})]}$, so haven't we already accounted for the uncertainty of $\beta$ by essentially 'averaging' it out?